# SciPy Newton Method

Tags: python-2.7, scipy, newtons-method

I need to find the roots of a quite complicated equation and I've read that python has a set of function that can help. I tried to figure out how they work but I failed pretty bad. The examples that I saw are all quite simple instead I need to find the roots of this function:

[image]

With B and K real positive numbers. Can anyone help ?

Comment: `I tried to figure out how they work but I failed pretty bad` please show what you tried and also include the errors you got.

Comment: No the point is that B and K are constants but they can change according to some parameter previously set. I can't understand how I can set them. I was thinking to define a function def f(x,B,K) but I don't know if it could  work.

Comment: *"I was thinking to define a function def f(x,B,K) but I don't know if it could work."*  That's the standard way to do it with the scipy optimization functions.  Give it a shot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two solutions, the second is probably the simpler and more correct way of solving the problem.

The trick is that you have to get the function `f` to remember the values of K and B. One way of doing this is to make it an inner function of another function. The outer function is used to set K and B. These are in the variable scope of the inner function that is returned. This way the inner `f` function can remember the values. The returned function is then simply passed on to the Newton-Raphson method, and it finds the root.

```
from scipy.misc import factorial
from scipy.optimize import newton
import numpy as np

def get_f(K=1, B=1):
    def f(x):
        return np.exp(-B*(np.power(B, x))-factorial(x)*K)
    return f

f = get_f(K=2, B=3)
print newton(f, 3, maxiter=1000)
```

A user commented that the `newton` function has an `args` argument, which can be used to pass extra arguments to the Newton-Raphson function. If the function has the form f(x, a, b, c...), then a, b, c... are extra arguments that can be given in `args`.

The same solution would then look like this:

```
from scipy.misc import factorial
from scipy.optimize import newton
import numpy as np

def f(x, K, B):
    return np.exp(-B*(np.power(B, x))-factorial(x)*K)

print newton(f, 3, args=(2, 3), maxiter=1000)
```

Comment: "*The trick is that you have to get the function f to remember the values of K and B."* No trick is needed.  Just the use `args` argument of `newton`.

Comment: Thank you @WarrenWeckesser, nice to know :)